# Why is NULL undeclared?

Tags: c++, syntax, nodes

I have a problem with this struct contructor when I try to compile this code:

```
typedef struct Node
{
    Node( int data ) //
    {
        this->data = data;
        previous = NULL; // Compiler indicates here
        next = NULL;
    }

    int data;
    Node* previous;
    Node* next;
} NODE;
```

when I come this error occurs:

```
\linkedlist\linkedlist.h||In constructor `Node::Node(int)':|
\linkedlist\linkedlist.h|9|error: `NULL' was not declared in this scope|
    ||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Last problem was the struct, but it worked fine when it was in my main.cpp, this time it's in a header file and is giving me this problem. I am using Code::Blocks to compile this code

Answer (score 160):

`NULL` is not a built-in constant in the C or C++ languages. In fact, in C++ it's more or less obsolete, just use a plain literal `0` instead, the compiler will do the right thing depending on the context.

In newer C++ (C++11 and higher), use `nullptr` (as pointed out in a comment, thanks).

Otherwise, add

`#include <stddef.h>`

to get the `NULL` definition.

Comment: NULL is part of stddef.h, not stdlib.h. Technically, you aren't guaranteed to get it as part of stdlib.h although I admit it would be pretty suprising if you didn't.

Comment: NULL is defined in the following C headers: stddef.h, stdlib.h, stdio.h, locale.h, string.h, and time.h (and wchar.h if you count C99).

Comment: OK, I stand corrected. I wonder why C++ needs to mention the contents of cstddef explicitly, and not the other headers. Perhaps it's considered the canonical 'C++' place for NULL whereas the other locations are for C compatibility?

Comment: @Charles Bailey C++ mentions cstddef explicitly because it defines NULL to 0 and not to ((void *)0) as in C99. This is because in C++ implicit casts from void * are forbidden.

Comment: Oh and in the upcoming C++0x there will be a new keyword null_ptr. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2105.html

Comment: I know why the standard needs to talk about the type of NULL, I just wonder why it only mentions one the places that its defined in the C standard library. At the moment, the new keywordin C++0x is still spelled 'nullptr'.

Comment: NULL is defined in quite a lot of C headers - and <stdlib.h> is one of those headers (C99 for sure; I don't think it changed between C89 and C99).  That said, <stddef.h> is the smallest header to use if you aren't using anything else from <stdlib.h>.  Also, given that this is C++, should that be <cstddef>?

Comment: >> Perhaps it's considered the canonical 'C++' place for NULL <<  I think this is correct. In the C standard, wherever it's mentioned that NULL is defined in a header other than stddef.h, there's always a note to see the description of NULL for stddef.h.

Comment: NULL, although a throw back to C is possibly better than '0', if for not other reason that when C++ 0x arrives with null_ptr, it will be easier to do a search & replace for NULL!

Comment: `<cstddef>` is the cleaner option.

Comment: DO NOT use "0" when you mean "NULL"!  There is a _difference_: semantics.  Never underestimate the importance of knowing what something is and using the right word, even if the compiler will let you get away with it!

Comment: @IanMallett: If you're talking about the fact that the null pointer is not guaranteed to be composed of binary zeroes you're mistaken. `0` in a pointer context is the null pointer, even if this may mean it's not a binary zero. You can even use the ASCII NUL char (one L) `'\0'` for the null pointer. Actually to add insult to injury you can use any integral **constant expression** of value zero (not just a literal) for the null pointer, including `3-2-1` or `!!!!!1`. Apparently Stroustrup thought all this was a funny thing to do (see TCPPPL paragraph on that).

Comment: @6502 Not talking about that; 0 and NULL do have the same value (almost) always, so using '\0' or 0 will accidentally work.  The problem is semantics.  Using NULL is more expressive, since it says that the value is question is a pointer, not just an integer.

Comment: It's incorrect that in C++ 0 and '\0' will work only accidentally. It will always work, according to C++ standard.

Answer (score 42):

Do use NULL. It is just #defined as 0 anyway and it is very useful to semantically distinguish it from the integer 0.

There are problems with using 0 (and hence NULL). For example:

```
void f(int);
void f(void*);

f(0); // Ambiguous. Calls f(int).
```

The next version of C++ (C++0x) includes `nullptr` to fix this.

```
f(nullptr); // Calls f(void*).
```

Comment: It's defined as `((void *)0)` by most C standard library implementations.

Comment: This is the  best **short** answer (and technically precise) I've ever read regarding the topic: NULL vs. 0 vs. nullptr. Thank you!

Comment: @SiPlus `((void *)0)` is incorrect in C++, because `void*` is not coercible to other pointer types the way it is in C. glibc, for instance, does `#define NULL 0` when `__cplusplus` is defined.

Answer (score 18):

Are you including "stdlib.h" or "cstdlib" in this file?  NULL is defined in stdlib.h/cstdlib

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

or

```
#include <cstdlib>  // This is preferrable for c++
```

Comment: NULL is part of stddef.h, not stdlib.h

Comment: @awiebe That was what I thought until five minutes ago - according to C99 quite a few different header files have to define it. Section 7.17 requires stddef.h to, 7.20 requires it in stdlib.h, and there are probably a good few others.

Answer (score 16):

`NULL` isn't a native part of the core C++ language, but it is part of the standard library. You need to include one of the standard header files that include its definition. `#include <cstddef>` or `#include <stddef.h>` should be sufficient.

The definition of `NULL` is guaranteed to be available if you include `cstddef` or `stddef.h`.  It's not guaranteed, but you are very likely to get its definition included if you include many of the other standard headers instead.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `NULL`, C++ allows you to use the unadorned `0` instead:

```
previous = 0;
next = 0;
```

And, as at C++11, you generally shouldn't be using either `NULL` *or* `0` since it provides you with `nullptr` of type `std::nullptr_t`, which is better suited to the task.

Comment: I tend think that NULL is useful documentation that you are intending to use a null pointer constant rather than an integer constant, although I don't object to using 0. I'll admit that you don't gain any practical benefits at the moment, but if/when you adopt the next C++ version it gives a good start for places to change to use the new nullptr constant.

Comment: i agree with you both, of course. Incidentally, it's both good that one documents one uses a pointer, but also good one documents that one actually puts an integer forward. consider  printf("%p\n", NULL); // OH, UB. Or if you have two overloads,  void f(int); void f(void*); you might think that f(NULL); calls the void* version when having a quick look on the call. f(0); will document the fact that it will actually call the int version, but won't document the fact that you intend you pass a pointer :( Good that nullptr fixes it :)