# is it right to use the new operator like this?

Tags: c++, new-operator

```
int main()
{
    int* nir = new int; // creating dynamic memory
    *nir = 7; // assigning value
    cout << *nir << endl;
    delete nir; // deleting 
    nir = 0; // **is this line for assigning the address nir=0? 0 is also part of memory right? Why didn't we put NULL?
    *nir = 8; // **can i do like this and change the value, so that the output can be 8 now?
    cout << *nir << endl;
    delete nir;
    nir = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code that I created to understand `new`. But, even though it was compiled fine by Code::Blocks, during the runtime, it crashes. I have two questions, which I have already mentioned in comment part.

```
nir = 0;
```

is this line for assigning the address `nir = 0`? 0 is also part of memory right? Why didn't we put `nir = NULL`?

```
*nir = 8;
```

can I do like this and change the value, so that the output can be `8` now? After all, I have already deleted the `*nir` value.

Comment: `nir = 0` makes `nir` point to nothing.. It's equivalent to setting it to `null`. After that, you can't do `*nir = 8` because `nir` has no memory allocated to hold 8. You deleted it using `delete`.

Comment: `nir = 0` and `nir = NULL` are absolutely the same thing.

Comment: @Jefffrey depending on what `NULL` has been defined as. `NULL`doesn't actually exist in C++. [It's a C thing, in a C library header](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12023528/85371)

Comment: ok, apparently, parts of the contents of these headers are in fact specified in the C++ standard (TIL; haven't checked). In that case, it still remains to be seen what `NULL` means in your context :)

Answer (score 0):

`nir=0;`

This sets the pointer to NULL. 0 and NULL are the same in this context.

`*nir=8`

This is wrong as nir in not a valid pointer. It's no suprise that it crashes!

`cout<<*nir<<endl;`

This is also wrong as nir is invalid pointer. You cannot read or write.

`delete nir;`

This is harmless, as deleting a NULL pointer is safe (it does nothing).

Comment: since I have already used int* nir=new int, does that mean that to yield the output 8, I have to allocate another dynamic memory with other name?

Comment: @Rockink I'm not sure what you mean. You have to allocate again, but you can use the same pointer. You can reuse the pointer again.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet is wrong

```
nir=0;     //**is this line for assigning the address nir=0? 0 is also part of memory right? Why didn't we put NULL?
*nir=8;    //**can i do like this and change the value, so that the output can be 8 now?
cout<<*nir<<endl;
delete nir;
nir=0;
```

You did not allocate memory and are trying to write to address 0.

```
*nir=8;    //**can i do like this and change the value, so that the output can be 8 now?
```

Usually the program will crash.

As for the line

```
nir = 0;
```

then it is equivalent to

```
nir = NULL;
```

In C++ NULL usualy defined as 0 or ( long )0 and so on.

According to the C++ Standard

> 1 A null pointer constant is an integer literal (2.14.2) with value
>   zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. A null pointer constant can
>   be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value
>   of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object
>   pointer or function pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged c++ so I recommend using nullptr instead of 0/NULL

`nir = nullptr;`

The problem

`The literal 0 (which is essentially of type int) also serves as a null pointer literal in C++. This kludge results in ambiguity and bugs.`

Solution

`Use the nullptr keyword instead of 0 to indicate a null pointer value`

[source](http://www.devx.com/cplus/10MinuteSolution/35167)

Answer (score 0):

A short breakdown of errors you purposely committed:

```
int main()
{
    int* nir = new int; // allocating dynamic memory
    *nir = 7; // assigning value
    cout << *nir << endl;
    delete nir; // deleting 
    nir = 0; // **is this line for assigning the address nir=0?
      // 0 is also part of memory right? Why didn't we put NULL?
```

The previous comment is wrong. For historical reasons, assigning a literal 0 to a pointer variable means setting it to a null pointer constant. This is not guaranteed to be 0 [!!!]. NULL and nullptr_t are more modern...

```
    *nir = 8; // **can i do like this and change the value,
      // so that the output can be 8 now?
    cout << *nir << endl;
```

On some systems you can do that. But your computing platform is now irretrievably corrupted. Modern systems catch the culprit and raise General Protection Fault, which only kills your program.

```
    delete nir;
```

Because programmers are keen to avoid useless work, the above (delete NULL) is defined as a no-op

```
    nir = 0;
    return 0;
```

The previous two lines are useless, as `nir` is never used again and `main` per standard returns 0 unless it explicitly doesn't, quite in contrast to any other function.

```
}
```