# C++ : NULL changing to 0

Tags: c++, null

I am calling a service which has some optional parameters.

I am setting the optional parameters as `NULL` .
But when i check the logs at service side, parameters passed as `NULL` have 0 numerical value.

Any idea why its happening and any way to prevent this ?

Comment: Because actually [NULL actually is a - macro with - numeric value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023476/what-header-defines-null-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

This is because `NULL` is usually set to `0` (on some systems it might be `0L`).  If you're using C++11/14, use `nullptr` instead.

Comment: On some systems, it is also `__nullptr`.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is *defined* as 0. It stands in for a null pointer.

Since it's a preprocessor definition, the run-time will not have access to the original token.

(The current C++ standard has `nullptr` instead. That *just* might be emitted into the runtime if you use it, depending on the capabilities of your debugger. As an important final remark, note that none of this implies that the actual *address* is zero, it's just the value that the null pointer chooses to take.)

Comment: This is true for many compilers, but the standard only requires `NULL` to be a "null pointer constant", which is an integral constant expression evaluating to 0.  At least one compiler defines it as `__nullptr`, a compiler built-in which evaluates to an integral `0`, but which is a separate token which survives pre-processing, and will cause a warning if it isn't immediately converted to a pointer type.

Comment: `std::cout << nullptr` is ambiguous. The conversions to `void const*` and `char const*` are equally good.  And I don't think you can legally add an overload for `operator<<( std::ostream&, std::nullptr_t )` (but I'm not sure).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any way to pass a C++ standard "null value" (`0`, `NULL` or `nullptr`) to a function and distinguish one from another. It will be output as zero either way. In other words, `NULL` is defined to be `0` in the C++ standard, and `0` and `nullptr` are interchangeable with regards to value - with only the difference that `nullptr` can only be assigned to something that is a pointer.

I wrote this code, and it outputs `p=0 q=0` for the first line, and `p = zero` and `q = zero` for the second line.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *p = nullptr;
    int *q = NULL;

    cout << "p=" << p << " q=" << q << endl;

    if (q == 0)
    {
        cout << "q = zero" << endl;
    }

    if (p == 0)
    {
        cout << "p = zero" << endl;
    }
}
```

If you want to, you could of course write your own translation for `0` to print `NULL` instead. Something like:

```
  if (p) 
     cout << p;
  else
     cout << "NULL";
```

But that gets a bit tedious, so I would just accept that `NULL` and `0` are the same thing.

(In code I write, I just use `0`, not `NULL` or `nullptr`)