# Trying to understand these structures

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to work out what is happening in a program that has no documentation whatsoever. Here's part of the code:

```
typedef struct
{
    UInt8 Access;
    UInt8 PDOMapping;
    UInt8 Size;
    void* Data;
    CheckValue Check;
    AccessEvent ReadEvent;
    AccessEvent WriteEvent;
}ObjectValue;

typedef struct
{
    UInt16          Index;
    UInt8           Code;
    ObjectValue*    Value;
}Object;

const UInt8 MaxSubIndex6400 = 1;    
ObjectValue Object6400Value[] = 
{
    {ACCESS_RO, MAP_NONE, 1, (void*)&MaxSubIndex6400, null, null},
    {ACCESS_RO, MAP_NONE, sizeof(Index6400Buffer), (void*)&Index6400Buffer, null, null, null}, 
};
```

The array of Object6400Value contains two items, but they have a different number of entries. Is this legal?

Comment: What is `null`?

Comment: Ah; I see that the 1st entry has no initializer for `WriteEvent`. If I remember well, then any initializer not provided will result in initializing to zero.

Comment: Yes, due to sorrounding `{}` that isolate a single `ObjectValue` item. Non initialized members are seto to `0`.

Comment: @unwind #define null   (void*)0

Comment: @DirkBruere That's seems ripe for a search-and replace to `NULL`, and add the proper `#include` (I like `<stddef.h>`, but it's defined by several, see [this answer for the list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12024299/28169)) to all relevant sources. No point in dragging around something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is legal.

The non-mentioned members will simply be default-initialized to 0.

The C11 draft standard says (in §6.7.9.21, page 141):

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are 
>   elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string 
>   literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements 
>   in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized 
>   implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

Comment: Yes, except this was written (apparently) in 2010 and earlier. Multiple nested structures, function pointers, variable names - none of it documented. Nightmare

Answer (score 2):

If there are too few initialisers for an aggregate, the remaining ones are initialised with zero.