# Issue with NULL and 0 behaving the same way

Tags: c++, class, constructor, nullptr

I was working on a class :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class Int{
    list <int64_t> data;
    bool sign;
public:
    Int(int64_t val = 0) : sign(false) {
        cout << "Int(int) called\n";
    }
    Int(const char* str): sign(false) {
        cout << "Int(const char* called)\n";
    }
};

int main(){
    Int a = "328739";     // line 1, ok
    Int a2 = "ehfjhs";    // line 2, ok
    Int a3 = 4338974;     // line 3, ok
    Int a4 = 0;    //line 4, Issue
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine, except line no 4.

As soon I do `Int a4 = 0;`, the constructor `Int(const char* str)` is called, as `0` is equivalent to `NULL`.  But I want `Int(int64_t val = 0)` to be called instead.

A simple fix I could make was doing `Int a4 = int(0);` that is ok on a side. But I want to make it flexible, so 0 triggers `Int(int64_t val = 0)` only.

Comment: I would recommend you to check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391703/how-does-function-overloading-work-when-passing-null-as-argument).

Comment: This is a fun one. Normally you'd make the constructor `explicit`, but that doesn't work with string literals. String literals convert to `const char *`, but avoiding conversion is what `explicit` is all about.

Comment: Add a static member function named like `from_str()` to construct from a string explicitly. All these implicit conversions are no good.

Comment: GCC and clang refuse to compile the code at all btw, on account of the ambiguity,

Comment: @rawrex thanks for that reference, that quite a bit clarifies this 0 and NULL thing ambiguity.

Comment: @SurajSingh you're welcome. Glad to help!

Comment: @SurajSingh that's why NULL shouldn't ever be used instead of nullptr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to the other answer, you can make a template constructor that accepts any integral type. This would resolve the ambiguity and additionally work for any integral type or literal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class Int{
    list <int64_t> data;
    bool sign;
public:
    template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>* = nullptr>
    Int(T val = 0) : sign(false) {
        cout << "Int(Integral) called\n";
    }
    Int(const char* str): sign(false) {
        cout << "Int(const char* called)\n";
    }
};

int main(){
    Int a = "328739";     // line 1, ok
    Int a2 = "ehfjhs";    // line 2, ok
    Int a3 = 4338974;     // line 3, ok
    Int a4 = 0;           // line 4, ok
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I had no idea it could be done that way too. Thanks @super

Comment: Simpler than what I was playing with: `explicit Int(const char* str): sign(false) { cout << "Int(const char* called)\n"; }` to prevent unwanted conversions and then `template <size_t N> Int(const char (&str)[N] ): sign(false) { cout << "string literal called)\n"; }` to handle string literals

Answer (score 2):

The key point here is that `0` is not an `int64_t`, so it has to go through an implicit conversion before being used in either of your constructors. Both constructors are equally valid here. gcc and clang actually flag the ambiguity as an error instead of arbitrarily picking one like you are experiencing.

The type of `0` is `int`, so if you have an `int` constructor, it will bind to `0` without going through any implicit conversion beforehand, which resolves the ambiguity:

```
class Int{
    list <int64_t> data;
    bool sign;
public:
    Int(int64_t val = 0) : sign(false) {
        cout << "Int(int) called\n";
    }
    Int(int val) : sign(false) {
        cout << "Int(int) called\n";
    }
    Int(const char* str): sign(false) {
        cout << "Int(const char* called)\n";
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks man! that resolved the issue. But I wonder why does it not work with int64_t only. I will see it.

Comment: Well@SurajSingh that's what the start of my answer covers. `0` being an `int`, it needs to be casted as a `int64_t` beforehand. However, there is no preference between implicitely casting 0 to a pointer or casting it to int64_t, so the compiler can't tell which constructor it's supposed to use. Modern compilers actually just flat out refuse to compile the code.

Comment: This is more an ad-hoc fix rather than a real solution.

Comment: @Evg I disagree. If OP wants their class to be constructible from any `int` literal as well as a pointer type , then having an `int` constructor that binds directly to the literal's type is exactly what they need.

Comment: Then why do you have a ctor that takes `int64_t`? Will this solution work with other integral types?

Comment: @evg I assumed OP still wants their int64_t constructor for the class' actual purpose. the issue is only the the `0` *literal*, integral types are fine in general. Pedantically, `0ul`would still cause issues, but that can be treated as an edge-case

Comment: @Evg your logic will also work for me, but I was looking for the compiler to do this by calling the appropriate constructor, so Frank's code does exactly the required thing in my case. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Try initializing `Int` with `0ll`, for example. It's pretty unexpected that `Int` can't be initialized with `0ll`, isn't it?