# NULL equals 0 in C, so should I treat both values like a nil?

Tags: c, lua, null, luajit

Afaik `NULL` can be (or really is, at least in my `stdlib` implementation) `#define`'d as:

```
#define NULL ((void*)0)
```

also, https://stackoverflow.com/a/924683/668125 states that in C++ NULL is transparently cast to/from `((int)0)` (which is the reason to use `std::nullptr` in C++ instead, since that has a real nil type/value pair thanks to the `nullptr_t` opaque typedef).

So, I'm currently developing a LuaJIT library and want to provide a helper function to check if a value is `nil`/`NULL`/whatever (=a value *meaning* `nil` but maybe not of type `nil`).

currently, that's:

```
function ffi.nil(value)
  return value==nil or value==ffi.NULL
end
```

but, a `(NULL==0)` in C would be true, as verified by this snippet printing `true` on my system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(void){
  if(NULL==0)
    printf("true\n");
  else
    printf("false\n");
}
```

so should I go for this definition of a "`nil` meaning value" instead?

```
function ffi.nil(value)
  return value==nil or value==ffi.NULL or value==0
end
```

**TL;DR:** in C, `NULL` is equal to `0`, while in LuaJIT's FFI, no two pairs of `nil, ffi.NULL, 0` are equal; so when defining what value should be considered a "`nil` like value" when dealing with 3rd party C libs, shall I include `0` or only `nil or ffi.NULL`?

Disclaimer: I'm afraid this might be considered an "opinion based question", so, in that case, I'll refine the question: Which behavior would more likely produce correct result, ignoring the fact that it could be considered good or bad style (so yes, if it's bad style but this particular style flaw is consistent between >50% of common libs, it's the way I'll have to do it)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`value == nil` will return true if `value` is a NULL cdata object.

```
LuaJIT 2.1.0-alpha -- Copyright (C) 2005-2014 Mike Pall. http://luajit.org/
JIT: ON SSE2 SSE3 SSE4.1 fold cse dce fwd dse narrow loop abc sink fuse
> ffi = require "ffi"
> print(ffi.new("void*", nil) == nil)
true
```

Thus, there's no point in your `ffi.nil` function. Just do `if value == nil`.

Note:

1. `if value then` won't work, because `value` is a cdata object and therefore evaluates to true, even though it is equal to `nil`. It's a bit confusing, but that's simply the way it is.
2. Replacing builtin functions and modifying builtin library tables is usually bad practice. You should define it as a local function instead, or as a library function instead.

Answer (score 1):

**1. ABOUT NULL IN C**

First, I analize what is `NULL` in C.

In the standard C99 document we can read, subsectiom 6.3.2.3:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression
>   cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant.

This defines the **null pointer constant**. 
In every implementation the macro `NULL` has to be defined as the null pointer constant.

> The macro NULL is deﬁned in  (and other headers) as a null pointer constant;

This means that there are only two possibilities to `#define` the macro `NULL`: `0` or `(void*)0`.

The null constant expression has two forms, as we see, but is not necessarilly considered a **null pointer**.
A conversion to a pointer type of the null pointer constant will bring a null pointer of **that type**.
The form `(void*)0` is per se a null pointer of type `void*`.

> Any two null pointers compare equal.

The equality operators are `==` and `!=` and they allow to compare arithmetic values, as much as pointer values, by following precise rules that I don't copy here. However, I will cite this:

> [For equality operators is allowed that] one operand is a pointer and
>   the other is a null pointer constant.

So, every pointer can be compared against `NULL` to check equality.

(Observe that not only pointer to objects are allowed, but pointer to functions also can be compared against `NULL`).

> If one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant,
>   the null pointer constant is converted to the type of the pointer.

This describes how the comparison against `NULL` is performed, just in case.

> Two pointers compare equal if [...] both are null pointers [...]

I cannot find the right place in the standard where a null pointer of some type, when compared against the null pointer constant, `NULL`, gives **true**. But, anyway, it is clearly intended that this is the expected behaviour.

We can conclude that, althoug every null pointer compared against `0` gives true, the `0` is not a null pointer, but an integer constant. The "real" null pointer value is not represented in any explicit way by the syntax of C, but only in indirect form.

**2. WHAT TO DO IN LUA**

Well, **I don't know Lua**, however because of you, I was looking around. There is some relation between Lua and C.

C has not a reserved word in the spirit of `nil` to represent null values.
The constant 0 is always an integer, not a pointer, but C compares it true against pointers having null value.
The `NULL` macro sometimes is defined as `(void*)0`, which is a pointer, but sometimes could be defined as merely `0`, which again is an integer.
Since `NULL` is a macro, is not what really matters.

So, I think that none of the options you are thinking reflects what is happening in C.
However, in general, it is used `NULL` to designate the null pointer in C.
I saw C functions in Lua, called in some special way.
On the other hand, I infere from your question that some kind of `.NULL` thing can be invoked.

**3. THE ANSWER**

My opinion is that your choice has to be `NULL`.
Since you are planning to use that function to check null pointers in C, take in account that in C, the functions that return pointers also can return the null pointer, which, in turn, can be passed as an argument to another functions.
If your functions are expected to return also non-null values and/or to cooperate with another functions related to C pointers, the value `NULL` will have to be available.
This would be my choice.

Anyway, I apologize because I am guessing here, since I don't have knowledge about Lua.

Comment: I know both C and Lua, so what to do for each of them isn't the problem, but when defining a function to decide whether something is nil/NULL across language boundaries. the "kind of `.NULL` thing" you mention is a userdata containing "the" NULL (=`(void*)0` wrapped as Lua userdata) pointer in LuaJIT's ffi library (so you can compare it a C function's return value you called from within Lua). so I can use both `nil` to check for a Lua function's `nil` return value and `ffi.NULL` to check for a C function's `NULL` return. but should I then still check for `tonumber(value)==0`?

Comment: If a C functions returns NULL, it means that its return type is "pointer to T", for some T. What is really returning is the "null value of type pointer to T". This value is not "0". As I have mentioned in my answer, `0` is always an integer constant, not a pointer value. This is explicitely stated in the standard C paragraph that I cited. So, you don't have to check for `tonumber(value)==0`.

Comment: ok, the "An integer constant expression with the value 0, […] is called a null pointer constant." made me wonder if maybe there are implementations actually defining NULL as `(int)0`, but even in that case, LuaJIT (when compiled for the target implementation) would also use that for `ffi.NULL`, so you're right, thanks :)

Comment: When the "null pointer constant" is defined as `0`, is not the "null pointer". This is funny, because the name "null pointer constant" suggest the contrary. The language C only "uses" the syntax `pointer == 0` to compare against the null pointer, but it is only a convention of the language. This doesn't mean that 0 can be considered a pointer.

Comment: ok, so that's just another one of the many cases where C isn't as strictly typed as it claims to be :D (I remember hunting for about a week for that one segfault randomly occurring every few hours in a big GTK application, just to find a pointer cast overflowing)