# Cannot add term to a listed list class

Tags: c++, oop, linked-list, abstract

I am trying to create a Polynomial class .The terms of each object should be sorted for an ease of use( from higher exponent to smaller one). So i do the sorting in the `addTerm` method but i am having some trouble doing it right. I either create an infinite linked list or the things are not sorted properly

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Polynomial {
protected:
    class Term {
    public:
        int exponent;
        int coefficient;
        Term *next;

        Term(int exp, int coeff, Term *n) {
            exponent = exp;
            coefficient = coeff;
            next = n;
        }
        friend class Polynomial;
    };

public:
    Polynomial() {
        root = NULL;
    }
    Polynomial(const Polynomial &p) {
        root = p.root;
    }
    ~Polynomial() {
        root = NULL;
    }
    void addTerm(int expon, int coeff) {

        Term *prev = root;
        Term *target = root;

        if (root == NULL) {
            Term tmp = Term(expon, coeff, NULL);
            Term *p = &tmp;
            root = p;

            return;
        }

        while (target!= NULL && target->exponent < expon) {
            prev = target;
            target = target->next;
        }

        if (prev == target){
            Term tmp = Term(expon, coeff, target;
            Term *p = &tmp;
            prev->next = p;
        }else{


        Term tmp = Term(expon, coeff, target);
        Term *p = &tmp;
        prev->next = p;

        }




    }



private:
    Term *root;
};

int main() {
    Polynomial q;
    q.addTerm(1, 4);
    q.addTerm(2, 3);
    q.addTerm(3, 4);
    //q.addTerm(1, 4);
    //q.addTerm(2, 4);
    // q.addTerm(2,4);
    //q.print();
    //cout << q;
}
```

Comment: Separate the concerns. The polynomial class is all tangled up with the implementation of a list. Use a list type to build the polynomial type. Best  would be to use a standard STL container like `std::list`. If a benighted instructor will not allow it, test your polynomial code using a standard list container to implement it, then try to roll your own list replacement.

Comment: both the main class and sub class methods should be as is ..

Comment: If you mean that your instructor said you must do it that way, well that's a shame. Just bear in mind that he is telling you to do it badly.  Get a good book.

Comment: I meant that the we only write the inside of each method not the name and their vars...cause they pass form a grader
...Also my instuctor worked at google for V8 js engine so  i must not explaining this correctly

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but no matter. Ask your instructor if you can use a standard list, and if not (unlikely given his credentials), if you can write a separate list class and incorporate it into polynomial.

Comment: I could do that but it works fine just addTerm has a problem..

Comment: Whatever. Good luck.

Comment: @JiveDadson "*If a benighted instructor will not allow it...*" OP shouldn't be allowed anywhere near the STL list given how they're struggling with a simple singly linked list implementation. They would have no idea what they were using or what it was doing! If this situation was in the workplace and you replaced "instructor" with "boss" I would agree with dubbing them "benighted," but academia is where you need to learn from the ground up.

Comment: @scohe001 I am aware that many instructors teach that way. I however agree whole-heartedly with Kate Gregory.  Learn from the sky down.
 I recommend this video very highly. https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk

Comment: @JiveDadson Touché. To each his own.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **lot** wrong here. I'm going to enumerate through some of what I see, but I don't think I'll be catching everything...

## 1. Don't use `NULL`

In your default constructor you set `root == NULL;`. Don't. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924664/why-is-null-undeclared) for more.

## 2. Your copy constructor makes a shallow copy.

`root = p.root;` means that both `root`'s are pointing to the same list! This means modifying one will modify the other which will result in some nasty surprises. You need to create a [deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657810/deep-copy-vs-shallow-copy).

## 3. Your destructor doesn't deallocate anything!

You set `root` back to the null pointer again and end the function. This is the equivalent of taking the trashbag out and setting it beside the can and considering the trash cleaned. You have memory leaks!

## 4. Your pointers all point to bad objects!

```
Term tmp = Term(expon, coeff, NULL);
Term *p = &tmp;
root = p;
```

Yipes! You allocate a `Term` locally and give `root` its address. But after that function ends, `tmp` goes out of scope and gets destroyed, leaving `root` pointing to an invalid memory location! You need to dynamically allocate memory that will persist for the life of the object.

Comment: 1. So you say to use `0`?
2.I know for the time being i dont' care....:P
3.How should i do it??
4.i tried `Term tmp = new(expon, coeff, target);` but i got an error

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis **1.** use `0` or `nullptr` if you can. `NULL` is deprecated, so you have no guarantee it will be valid. **3.** Every call to `new` requires a matching call to `delete` (otherwise you have leaks). You'll need to loop through and call delete on each Term you've allocated. **4.** try `Term *tmp = new Term(expon, coeff, target);`